# clojure terminating parenthesis syntax

Tags: clojure, compiler-construction, parentheses

Is there any reason why the expression

```
(foo5 (foo4 (foo3 (foo2 (foo1 arg)))))
```

cannot be replaced with

```
(foo5 (foo4 (foo3 (foo2 (foo1 arg)-)
```

or the like, and then expanded back?

I know lack of reader macros means that you cannot change syntax, but can this expansion possibly be hard coded into the java?

I do this when I hand write code.

Comment: how would `(foo7 (foo6 (foo5 (foo4 (foo3 (foo2 (foo1 arg1)-) arg2)-)` be parsed?

Comment: I recall reading about a Lisp that had something like this.  I think it used `]` to mean "close all open parentheses".  I have a suggestion, though.  Even without `->`, piled up parentheses are not really a problem once (a) one becomes familiar with standard Clojure code formatting, and (b) one uses an editor that can apply standard Clojure formatting rules.  You can then see whether you've got the right number of right-parens by seeing whether the formatting chosen by the editor is what you expected.  (And of course one should always use an editor that matches parentheses.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could do this, even without reader macros (in fact, you can change Clojures syntax with a bit of hacking).

But, the question is, what would it gain you? Would it always expand to top-level? But then cutting and pasting code would fail, if you moved it to or from top level. And, of course, all the various tools that operate of clojure syntax would need to understand it.

Ultimately if you really dislike all the close parens why not use

```
(-> arg foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4)
```

instead?

Comment: Yes, when hand writing code -> seems conceptually better - coding using -> must be better also - I'll look it up. Win. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this could be done, but I'm not sure it is the right solution and there are a number of negatives which will likely outweigh the benefits.

Suggestions like this are often the result of poor coding tools and a 'traditional' conceptual model for writing code. Selecting the right tools and looking at your code from a slightly different perspective will usually eliminate the cause which lead to this type of suggestion.

Most of the non-functional, non-lispy style languages are based around a token and line model of code. You tend to think of the code in terms of lines of tokens and you tend to edit the code on this basis. There is typically less nesting of expressions and lines are usually terminated with some marker, such as a semi-colan. Likewise, tools such as your editor, have features which have evolved to support token and line based editing. They are good at it.

The lisp style languages are less focused on lines of tokens. The emphasis here is on list forms. lines of tokens are replaced with nested lists of symbols - the line is less relevant and you typically have a lot more nesting of forms. This change means your standard line oriented tools, like your editor, are less suitable. The typical mental model of the code as lines of tokens is also less useful.

With languages like Clojure, your better off thinking in terms of list forms and not lines of code. Once you make this transition, you then start looking for tools which also model the code along these lines. For example, you either look for editors specifically designed to work with lists of data rather than lines of data or you look for editors which have extensions which will allow you to work with lists.

Once your editor understands that lists are the fundamental grouping unit, not lines, things like parenthesis become largely irrelevant from a code writing/editing perspective. You don't worry about closing parenthesis, counting parenthesis nesting levels etc. This all gets managed by the editor automatically. You don't move by lines, you move by lists, you don't kill/delete a line, you kill a list, you don't cut and copy a block of lines, you cut and copy a list of lists etc.

The good news is that in many respects, the structure of these list based code representations are actually easier to manipulate than most of the line based languages. This is primarily because there is less ambiguity or complexity. There are fewer exceptions to the rules and the rules are inherently simple. As a consequence, many editors designed for programmers will have support for this style of coding as well as advanced features which are difficult to implement in less structured code.

My suspicion is that your suggestion to have an additional bit of syntactic sugar to avoid having to type multiple closing parenthesis is actually a symptom of not having the right tools to write your code. Once you do, you will almost never need to enter a closing parenthesis or count opening parens to ensure you get the nesting right. This will be handled by the editor. Your biggest challenge will be in shifting your mental model to think in terms of lists and lists of lists. The parens will become largely invisible and you will jump around in your code according to list units rather than line units. The change is not easy and it can take some time to re-train your brain and fingers, but once you do, you will likely be surprised at how quickly you begin to edit and manipulate your code.

If your an emacs user, I highly recommend extensions such as paredit and lispy. If your using some other editor, look for paredit type extensions. However, as these are extensions, you must also spend some time training yourself to use whatever the key bindings are that the extension uses - there is no point having an extension with great code navigaiton based on lists if you still just arrow around with the arrow keys (unless it is emacs and you have re-bound those arrow keys to use the paredit navigation bindings).